# Calling Instance Variables without @

Tags: ruby, instance-variables

I'm new to Ruby programming and I've seen a few examples now where an instance variable is being called without the "@" symbol in front of it.

I'm not sure if this because the method is being called and the instance variable is stored in the method as a result of a `attr_reader` in the class or if because I have the wrong understanding of instance variables.

Here's an example of what I'm referring to taken from Russ Olsen's Eloquent Ruby, where the `@unique` array has the `size` method called on it without the "@" symbol in front of it:

```
class TextCompressor
attr_reader :unique, :index

def initialize(text)
    @unique = []
    @index = []
    add_text(text)
end

def add_text(text)
    words = text.split
    words.each { |word| add_word(word) }
end

def add_word(word)
    i = unique_index_of(word) || add_unique_word(word)
    @index << i
end

def unique_index_of(word)
    @unique.index(word)
end

def add_unique_word(word)
    @unique << word
    unique.size - 1
end
end
```

Comment: You're on the right path, it is because of attr_reader.

Answer (score 3):

I'm also new to Ruby and have been learning for a couple weeks. I believe:

```
attr_reader :unique
```

is functionally identical to defining the method:

```
def unique
  @unique
end
```

Comment: This is correct. You don't need to apologize for being a learner, or a beginner. We all continue to learn and were all beginners once. And, if you are unsure of an answer it might be useful to test it and make sure you have example output in your answer to back up the answer. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

attr_reader creates method with the name of the argument you supplied, returning a instance variable with same name. eg: -

```
attr_reader :name
```

it will create a method at runtime like this

```
  def name
    @name
  end
```

and same with attr_writer, it creates a setter method for that argument like

```
attr_writer :name

def name=(value)
  @name = value
end
```

and, attr_accessor creates both getter and setter with the name of the argument you supplied.

Comment: So the method "name" is defined and creates the @name instance variable... this allows name.size to be called on the name instance variable? Isn't that a method calling another method?

Comment: @EMK428 yes to your question. in ruby all data is private you can only access it with methods

Comment: So a method can be called on another method if that method contains an instance variable? If a method named foo had an instance variable named @bar that contained an array ['a','b','c'], if foo.size was called the answer would be 3 despite the fact there is no foo array?

Comment: @EMK428, methods are being called on value of instance variable, that is an array object, it has nothing to do with instance variable.

Comment: I understand that... what I was saying confused me is that a method can be defined with the name "foo" and contain an instance variable bar that contains an array ["a","b","c"] and foo.size would return 3. The instance variable isn't present in the "foo.size" method call and so I was just saying that as a novice Ruby programmer this confuses me. I was wondering why it was considered good practice to write method_name.size versus instance_variable.size. So why foo.size would be called versus @bar.size.

Answer (score 1):

You don't "call" instance variables, but you call methods. Your assumption is right, that you do an actual method call without the "@". The `attr_accessor :unique, :index` is basically equivalent to:

```
def unique
  @unique
end

def unique=(val)
  @unique = val
end

def index
  @index
end

def index=(val)
  @index = val
end
```

That you can write `unique = val` when a `unique=(val)` method is defined is syntactic sugar provided by Ruby to make it look like a variable assignment, even though it's actually a method call.

In general you shouldn't mix the different ways of referencing the instance variable in one method though. If a method has to know the implementation details of how the value is stored, you can use the direct access with `@`. Otherwise, you should use the accessor methods. The less code is relying on implementation details, the better. Even if it's inside instance methods of the respective instance.

Comment: So you're saying that the code should've been written @unique.size - 1 or that if you don't need to write the "@" symbol not to write it. This example is from Eloquent Ruby by Russ Olsen. I also saw this type of method calling in TestFirst Ruby problems that I completed.

Comment: Is this possible because methods are objects themselves?

Comment: @EMK428: That's correct, he either should use `@unique.size - 1` or (even better) `unique << word` instead. Because the unique method is returning a reference to the instance variable, it's working as a left hand value here. Bear in mind, that assignments like `unique = []` can lead to unexpected behavior: if there is no unique= writer method defined, Ruby interprets this as an implicit variable declaration. You can avoid that by prefixing it with `self.`, but I don't like that because it restricts the visibility the accessor method can be to protected or higher (and it's more verbose).

Comment: @theTinMan: That's right, I didn't look right. But because he had problems distinguishing instance variables from method calls, I was assuming he might have been confused by their use in left hand assignments. Since his question was more generally about "Calling Instance Variables" I think covering both (readers and writers) here is more helpful.

Comment: @EMK428: To your other question: ruby methods are not objects (even though you can create Proc and Method objects, but that's another matter). The "." is just an operator (like "+" etc) which says: evaluate the left hand side of this expression and send the message of the right hand side to the resulting object. Because ruby knows the `unique` expression in `unique.size` isn't an object but a method, it knows that it has to call unique first and than call the "size" method on whatever object this method returns. (That doesn't have to be an instance variable.)

Answer (score 0):

The line :

```
attr_reader :unique, :index
```

creates getter methods for unique and index like :

```
def unique
 @unique
end
```

So when you call :

```
unique.size
```

It first calls the getter method which returns @unique and then size method on it.